# - DisableCustomAppAuthentication Parameter not found on Sharepoint Command set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, authentication, pnp-powershell

I want to enable custom app authentication by disabling the tenant property `-DisableCustomAppAuthentication` on SharePoint online

I have tried the below commands but I am getting error parameter not found:

```
set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

Set-PnPTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false
```

Error while using PnP PowerShell:

```
Set-PnPTenant : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DisableCustomAppAuthentication'.
At line:1 char:15
+ Set-PnPTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-PnPTenant], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Admin.SetTenant
```

Error while using SharePoint PowerShell:

```
Set-SPOTenant : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DisableCustomAppAuthentication'.
At line:1 char:15  + set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-SPOTenant], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SetTenant
```

Comment: Which version of PnP PowerShell are you using? Try using [latest version 1.8.0](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/releases). As per the [release notes](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases), this parameter has been added in Oct 2020 release.

Comment: Thank you, it worked . I have to uninstall the   SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline and install it again. Uninstall-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -force                                      Install-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I have added my comments as answer below, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [release notes](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases), `-DisableCustomAppAuthentication` parameter has been added in October 2020 release.

Try using [latest version (1.8.0)](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/releases) of PnP PowerShell & it should work for you.

Follow below documentation for more information: [PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -RequiredVersion 16.0.20414.12000
```

This is the only version I found that had access to that property. Otherwise I received the same error message as mentioned in the question.